# Learning how to integrate JavaScript with other languages

Tags: web-development, javascript, web-applications

After learning JavaScript syntax, what are some good resources for learning about integrating JavaScript with other languages (HTML, XML, CSS, PHP) to create real, useful applications?

I'm most interested in reading articles or other people's code - not so interested in books. Basically, I'm looking to move from programming puzzle-solvers to programming complex applications and could use some advice.

Comment: Cloud9IDE is open source. Get stuck in that. it's probably the biggest js integration of client and server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend anything involving AJAX (asynchronous Javascript and XML, but it really means any Javascript web app that sends HTTP requests), because it's a good way to force yourself to integrate JavaScript, HTML, XML (optionally), and a server-side language like PHP at the same time.  I don't really have any non-book resources to link to (other than just Googling for articles on "Ajax" and "XMLHttpRequest"), but if you can solve a problem such as building a live chatroom I think you'll have a good grasp on the technologies are all related.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second what @eds said about AJAXy-type applications. I wouldn't build a complete site on them, nor would I make a site *dependent* on JavaScript being enabled, but a little AJAX can be nice. Unfortunately, I *hate* the whole `XMLHttpRequest` mess with callbacks, handlers, etc.

The good news is that a very large number of AJAX interactions can be achieved much more simply by using the [taconite plugin for jQuery](http://jquery.malsup.com/taconite/). IMNSHO, this is a must-have plugin for jQuery. I believe there may also be taconite extensions for other JS frameworks.

Taconite basically creates a [fire-and-forget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire-and-forget) environment. You send off your request to the server and then ... don't worry about it. Taconite intercepts the return package. It allows for multiple DOM changes in a single exchange, including `eval()` of JS fragments.

Seriously, check this one out.

Answer (score 0):

If you know these languages you mentioned it is very easy to integrate Js with these . Specially with Html and css  cause these are client side application .. With php and c# also its not that tricky

Comment: Why the downvote? This sounds like useful advice. Is it wrong?